# How to hide website content until it's fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, load, hidden

I tried this:

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("konteineris").style.visibility = "display";
};
```

CSS:

```
.konteineris {
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

And the thing is that browser doesn't load content at all. All it loads - some iframes and that's all.

Website: http://mamgrow.lt/

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Look at: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uPAdepO/2/edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change class selector `.konteineris` to ID selector `#konteineris`:

```
#konteineris {
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

and in html change `<div class="konteineris">` to `<div id="konteineris">`

Or you need just change your JS to:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementsByClassName("konteineris")[ 0 ].style.visibility = "display";
};
```

Also there is no `display` value in `visibility` CSS property. So should be:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementsByClassName("konteineris")[ 0 ].style.visibility = "visible";
};
```

Comment: Such a stupid mistake... I fixed it, and yes it only works with visible for me. Thank you alot! Any ideas, why some parts shows before div being fully loaded?

Comment: @IgnasDamunskis what some parts do you mean? `Google+` button?

Comment: Google+ and iframe YT video, they both are within konteineris div.

Comment: This happens because 3rd party widgets adds `visibility: visible;` in inline `style` attribue. I guess you can't control this. The only thing you can do is append them after page is showed using JS

Comment: @IgnasDamunskis just add `!important` to visibility and that's all. `visibility: hidden !important;`

Answer (score 1):

**CSS3 fadeIn**

Here is an example using the modern css3 keyframes feature.

**CSS**

```
body{
  opacity:0;
}
body.show{
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn 5s ease;
  opacity:1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{
    0%{opacity:0;}
    100%{opacity:1;}
}
```

to add more support you need to manually add the various prefixes

```
-webkit -ms -moz -o ....
```

**JS**

```
window.onload=function(){
 document.body.className='show';
}
```

btw in this case i think the javascript part isn't necessary as the css style applies when the element is created. so basically the next code should be enough.

```
body{
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn 5s ease;
  opacity:1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{
    0%{opacity:0;}
    100%{opacity:1;}
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/ZHKUA/1/

if you have any questions just ask.

Comment: You can! it's already (by default) wrapped with window.onload function, so you should change to no wrap - body or head.